# Android ICS SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas() failed internally and returns null

Tags: android

I got the sample project BasicGLSurfaceView and modified it to simulate an issue which we are facing in our project.
I modified the Activity to use the luckCanvas API of SurfaceHolder of GLSurfaceView:

```
public class BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { //Added a on click listener to draw some text on the view

......

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        mView = new BasicGLSurfaceView(getApplication());
        mView.setOnClickListener(this); // adding the on click listener 
        setContentView(mView);
    }

.............

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Toast message
        AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Canvas lockCanvas = mView.getHolder().lockCanvas(); // Trying to get canvas to draw something
                if(lockCanvas!=null){
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    paint.setTextSize(36.0f);
                    lockCanvas.drawText("Hello usgin locked canvas", 10, 50, paint);
                    mView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(lockCanvas);
                }
                return null;
            }

        };

        asyncTask.execute();

    }
}
```

If you check this code, you'll see that the lockCanvas is always null and the following error is shown inside logcat:

```
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:771)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:747)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at com.example.android.basicglsurfaceview.BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity$1.doInBackground(BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity.java:61)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at com.example.android.basicglsurfaceview.BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity$1.doInBackground(BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity.java:1)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-02 00:29:39.260: E/SurfaceHolder(1245):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

But this code is working in GingerBread without any issue.
Could you please explain what changes in Ice Cream Sandwich causes this issue or what would be the workaround to solve this issue?

Additionally, I am getting the following error too:

```
12-21 10:04:47.254: E/EglHelper(17382): eglSwapBuffers returned EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW. tid=1507
12-21 10:04:47.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17382): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1507
12-21 10:04:47.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17382): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
12-21 10:04:47.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17382):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1178)
12-21 10:04:47.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17382):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1136)
12-21 10:04:47.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17382):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1463)
12-21 10:04:47.285: E/AndroidRuntime(17382):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

Thanks a lot.